# How to create a numpy array filled with points of a circle using rasterio module?

Tags: python, numpy, raster, rasterio

I am using the rasterio module to transfer a raster image into a numpy array. From that numpy array, I want to extract a sub-array, that will consist only of points of a circle. The circle will be defined from a given point (indexes x and y from the starting numpy array) and a radius (distance in meters). Rasterio can handle real life distance (meters and not indexes) that every cell represents. But I cannot find a function to get cells in a specific distance from a given point.

Comment: It is unclear to me what the actual problem is. Is the problem about how to convert metres to pixels? Or is it about working out which pixels are within a radius from a point? Or is it about trying to store a round shape in a rectangular image and wondering what goes outside the circle?

Comment: Every pixel --> 5m. I want to select a point in my array (e.g. indexes 100,100) and create a circle around it with a radius of 100m. Can I create a circle by giving the distance in meters? If my raster file is squared-grided, then I can translate the cell size into pixel size (1 pixel --> 5 meters, so a radius 100m --> 20 pixels). But what if every pixel has different distance in the y and the x axis? After I solve that, I have to get an array and fill it with the points that are located from a specific point a radius distance away (i.e. they construct a cirlce)

Comment: does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865023/circular-masking-an-image-in-python-using-numpy-arrays) help?

Comment: it doesn't answer the problem when a pixel is not a square.