# get all the point that inside a circle

Tags: python, image-processing

Hi i have an image and i draw a circle on it.

Now i want to get all the points that inside the circle, but when i tried to do something on that points i get indexoutofbounds exception, or i get the wrong points.

the code that i did to get all that points is:

```
l1 = [(i,j) for i, j in itertools.product(range(height), range(width)) if 
(i-x1)**2 + (j-y1)**2 < radius**2]
```

how can i get all the points that inside the circle, and why my code doesn't work?

Edit:
Now its works, i dont get why

code:

```
for i in range(width-1):
        for j in range(height-1):
            if (i - x1)**2 + (j-y1)**2 < radius**2:
                l1.append((i,j))
```

and to get the pixels i do:

```
for (i,j) in l3:
   img[j,i,0] = 255
   img[j,i,1] = 255
   img[j,i,2] = 255
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular masking an image in python using numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865023/circular-masking-an-image-in-python-using-numpy-arrays)

Comment: are you sure that the units of `x1`, `y1`, and `radius` match the units of `range(height)`, i.e. `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...]`? Cause if radius is, say, 0.1, and height is 0.5, this ain't gonna work...